# PHP jQuery .post .get, is this the right way?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is submitted version of my application about browser javascript saving data to server and loading it from server using .post and .get jQuery ajax calls.

`returnState` is added to submitted code to show its received from the Server (for testing purposes, to tell what to receive).

**Save Javascript code:**

```
var text = [];
text = {
    text: "Text to be saved.",
    returnState: "success"
};
$.post("Save.php", {
    datatype: "json",
    text : JSON.stringify(text)
});
```

**Server save PHP code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$json = $_REQUEST['text'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $json = stripslashes($json);
$new = (array)json_decode($json);
$_SESSION['savedText'] = $new['text'];
echo $new['returnState'];
?>
```

**Load Javascript code:**

```
var text = [];

$.get("Load.php", {
    returnState: 'success'
}).done(function (data) {
    text = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(text.returnState);
    console.log(text.text);
});
```

**Server load PHP code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$returnValues = array(
    text => json_decode($_SESSION['savedText']),
    returnState => $_SESSION['returnState']
);
echo json_encode($returnValues);
?>
```

- In case of error, I will not get proper data which can be interpreted it failed. Should I use `.fail()` instead?
- In case I would like to not use own `returnState`, what/how PHP response can make jQuery fall into `.fail()`?
- I worked hard to make the PHP array right from serialized text in the Server PHP Load code, is that good way?

Comment: the request fails if there is an error on server side(returns a non 200 code) or there is a connectivity problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use .fail with .done
- Use 4xx http codes instead of custom "returnState". It will fire .fail function

P.S. Don't use $_REQUEST. Use $_GET and $_POST instead.

P.P.S. Don't use "magic quotes", it's deprecated in newer php versions.

Answer (score 0):

the $.post should be as follows

```
$.post("Save.php", {text : JSON.stringify(text)}, 'text');
```

Comment: no need to serialize it can be just be `$.post("Save.php", text, 'text');`

Answer (score 0):

The data you send should be the second parameter, no need to serialize it

```
$.post('Save.php', text);
```

if you need a success callback function it has to be the third parameter

```
$.post('Save.php', text, function(data) {
  console.log('all good!');
});
```

if you need to specify data type for the return data it has to be the fourth parameter

```
$.post('Save.php', text, function(data) {
  console.log('all good!');
}, 'json');
```

if you need a failure callback you have to use `deferred` syntax:

```
$.post('http://www.asd.it', text, function(data) {
  console.log('all good!');
}).fail(function() {
  console.log('error');
});
```

bottom line: learn to use documentation